# Browser Sync - PHP and htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, gulp, yeoman, browser-sync

I'm currently using the **Yeoman Generator Gulp-Webapp**, which I modified slightly to make it work with PHP. I simply added gulp-connect-php & http-proxy then edited the gulpfile.babel.js browserSync task by adding the following code. Now I would need to **find a way to make it work with htaccess**. Any idea how this could be done?

```
gulp.task('serve-php', ['styles', 'fonts'], () => {
  phpConnect.server({
    port: 9001,
    base: 'app',
    open: false
  });
  const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    open: true,
    port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: ['.tmp', 'app'],
      routes: {
        '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
      },
      middleware: function (req, res, next) {
        var url = req.url;
        if (!url.match(/^\/(styles|fonts|bower_components)\//)) {
          proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:9001' });
        }
        else {
          next();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  gulp.watch([
    'app/**/*.html',
    'app/**/*.php',
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    'app/images/**/*',
    '.tmp/fonts/**/*'
  ]).on('change', reload);

  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
  gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep', 'fonts']);
});
```

Comment: what kind of error do you get by apache?

Comment: The htaccess file isn't read at all so I don't get any error. In fact, it's not an apache server, but a 'virtual' server by node.js.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work with PHP and htaccess!

Instead of using gulp-connect-php to create the vhost, I used XAMPP. I then target the proxy to the XAMPP vhost. Here's how I did it:

```
gulp.task('serve-php', ['styles', 'fonts'], () => {
  const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    open: true,
    port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: ['.tmp', 'app'],
      routes: {
        '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
      },
      middleware: function (req, res, next) {
        var url = req.url;
        if (!url.match(/^\/(styles|fonts|bower_components)\//)) {
          proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://xamppvhost.dev' });
        }
        else {
          next();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  gulp.watch([
    'app/**/*.html',
    'app/**/*.php',
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    'app/images/**/*',
    '.tmp/fonts/**/*'
  ]).on('change', reload);

  gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
  gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep', 'fonts']);
});
```

I removed phpConnect.server() and changed the proxy.web() to target my XAMPP vhost.

Now everything's working!!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can still be usefull for those bumping into this.

If you're developing on Mac, you can use MAMP and **gulp-mamp**, by far the easiest way to get things working - PHP, htaccess and MySQL if need be.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-mamp

After installing, you can get things to work with just this code in your gulpfile:

```
var mamp = require('gulp-mamp');
gulp.task('mamp-start', function(cb){
    mamp(options, 'start', cb);
});
```

And then adding the task to the default task, or via command `gulp mamp-start`.

**Mamp + Browser sync**

is also very easy, just copy the code from this gulpfile:

https://github.com/sdotson/gulp-mamp-browsersync/blob/master/gulpfile.js